# Discord.py roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, roles

I want to send message if the author has the role, but if I try this code it doesn't work (id of role is right).

```py
@client.command()
async def role(ctx):
    roles = ctx.author.roles
    for x in roles:
        if x.id == '850644250152665098':
await ctx.send("Role")
```

Comment: IDs are integers, not strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`discord.Role.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.id) returns an integer value. That means that you cannot compare it with a string. All you have to do is change `if x.id == '850644250152665098':` to `if x.id == 850644250152665098:`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to resolve this issue and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a `str` to an `int` in addition to that the last line is not indented well

```py
@client.command()
async def role(ctx):
    for role in ctx.author.roles:
        if role.id == 850644250152665098:
            await ctx.send(f"Role {role.name} has been found")
```